# How to implement a recommendation system in Java for Android application(s)?

Tags: java, android, recommendation-engine

I want to apply recommendation system in my Android app. But many articles and books use Python and list/ array in their examples. I like to know how we can implement the system in Java and online database. Should I run the code on client-side or do it as CRON job?

Comment: Which algorithm do you plan to use for recommendation? There are many options. Also, they usually require a lot of data, and it takes some time to process it, so it's usually done at dedicated (and powerful) server.